# How to use textfieldname.text and textfield.placeholder in ios 7 by using UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

How to achieve textfieldname.text and textfield.placeholder functionality for ios 7? I had used following code.

```
UIAlertView* dialog = [[UIAlertView alloc] init];
[dialog setDelegate:self];
[dialog setTitle:@"Title"];
[dialog setMessage:@" "];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
[dialog addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

[dialog setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];

[dialog show];
```

At sometime i want to load some data into textfield like "Welcome" is loaded in textfield if user need then they can modify test into "Welcome to stackoverflow". Is it possible to achieve that functionality? Advance thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UITextField *textField = [dialog textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.text = @"Some Text";
textField.placeholder = @"Some Placeholder";
```

More info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/textFieldAtIndex:

Comment: @Sakthimuthiah this doesn't add a subview. When you set your `alertViewStyle` to `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput` the alert view automatically added the textField for you. You can then use `textFieldAtIndex:` to access it.

Comment: Okay i will try and come back to you

Answer (score 1):

in another way

The UIALertView has a textFieldAtIndex: method that returns the UITextField object you want.

For a UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput, the index of the textfield is 0.

You can then set the placeholder (or text) property of the textfield:

```
UIAlertView * dialog = ....
UITextField *textField = [dialog textFieldAtIndex:0];
textField.placeholder = @"your text";
```

reference : UIAlertView Class Reference

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setting up the delegate for the UIAlert as well as UITextfield. Can be worked as:

```
[[dialog textFieldAtIndex:0] setDelegate:self];
 UITextField *alertTextField = [dialog textFieldAtIndex:0];
```

By becoming the delegate for the input text field you can find out when the return key on the keyboard is pressed. Then in the .m file for your class you implement the delegate method below and tell the alert to disappear:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
[self.dialog dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.scanCode.firstOtherButtonIndex animated:YES];
return YES;
}
```